# How to configure resource server to accept access token (Oauth2) Spring Boot / Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, azure, spring-boot, ionic-framework, oauth-2.0

I have a question about how to configure my Spring Boot server as a resource server while receiving access tokens from my mobile app build in Ionic 3.

I am using Azure Active Directory for users to login, and because I want users to login on my application I am using the Implicit OAuth2 flow. In my Ionic app I use this (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) apache cordova plugin to show a login form (from Microsoft AAD) and with the correct credentials I recieve an access token and an expiration date.

[image]

I am using my Spring Boot application as a REST API. The users in the mobile app call endpoints like:

```
https://localhost:8080/period
https://localhost:8080/declaration/1
etc...
```

Ofcourse I want to protect these resources as anyone can call them right now. Right now I send the access tokens in the Authorization header something like this:

```
let host = "https://localhost:8080/";    
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization',access_token);
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
consle.log(this.http.get(this.host + "period",options));
```

I have been looking for tutorials,docs, stack topics etc... all day but I cannot find the case that I am looking for where I send the access token to the resource server. Also I have a hard time understanding what is going on in those tutorials. So far this is what I managed to understand and what I have in my spring boot application:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false, securedEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/period/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/files/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/declaration/**").hasRole("USER");
    }


}
```

The questions that I have is:

How do I manage to process the access code and return resources to the user?

[image]

**EDIT:**

So I tried to use a Filter to intercept incoming HTTP traffic and get the token from the header like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.BearerTokenExtractor;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.TokenExtractor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter implements Filter,InitializingBean {

    private final static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);

    private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor = new BearerTokenExtractor();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("Initialize OAuth2 filter");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Do filter");

        final boolean debug = logger.isDebugEnabled();
        final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        System.out.println(req.getHeader("Authorization"));
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Destroying OAuth2 filter");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

But the filter (doFilter) will only be called when I set my configuration like this:

```
.antMatchers("/period/**").permitAll()
```

If I use it like this the filter (doFilter) will not get called (init still calls):

```
.antMatchers("/period/**").permitAll()
```

So I assume that a filter is not the way to go here?

**EDIT**: So I got this working after I found this Github Repo providing everything I need:

https://github.com/yuhuachang/spring-boot-oauth2-azuread

Answer (score 0):

The main thing your resource server (API) will need to do is to validate received access tokens and there are 2 methods:

- **OPTION 1**

Introspection, where your API externalizes validation to the Authorization Server. This is the technique I prefer. I have been writing a blog on the concepts at http://authguidance.com and Step 12 of [this page](http://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) shows what an Introspection request from your API to the Authorization Server would look like.

- **OPTION 2**

However, I don't think Azure AD has an introspection endpoint, so looks like the option you need is manual in memory validation. Your API's code needs to get public key information about how Azure AD signs tokens, then use Microsoft OWIN libraries to do the work. [This article](https://d-fens.ch/2017/04/13/manual-jwt-validation-against-azure-active-directory/) describes that type of option.

Let me know if you continue to struggle - I'll be happy to drill a bit deeper for you if it helps.

Gary

Comment: I am using Spring Boot which is Java. I don't think the OWIN library is available for Spring Boot.